# How do I prevent slime from starting sldb on certain errors?

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, sbcl, slime, hunchentoot

When serving large files from Clack/Hunchentoot with Slime connected, I sometimes see error messages like SB-IMPL::SIMPLE-STREAM-PERROR "Couldn't write to ~s"... Those are caused by the browser prematurely dropping connections (which is totally OK). The problem is that each time it happens, SLDB pops up. Which is annoying.

Is there a way I can inhibit certain errors in SLDB such as the above? I still would like to see them in an error log, but definitely not in SLDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Since your system uses Hunchentoot, you could set the global variable `HUNCHENTOOT:*CATCH-ERRORS-P*` to `T`. This should guarantee that the all the conditions arising in code managed by Hunchentoot are catched by Hanchentoot itself and not passed to the debugger.

To disable the debugger in any Common Lisp implementation (both inside a shell REPL as well as the Slime REPL inside Emacs) you could use the predefined global variable [*debugger-hook*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_debugg.htm), by assigning to it a two argument function. The function will receive the condition and the current value of *debugger-hook* when it is called, and can handle the condition or return normally, and in this case the debugger is invoked. For instance, you could simply print the condition:

```
* (defun my-debug(condition hook)
    (declare (ignore hook))
    (print condition)
    (abort))

DEBUG-IGNORE
* (setf *debugger-hook* #'my-debug)

#<FUNCTION MY-DEBUG>
```

This second method however cannot work when using Hunchentoot together with Slime, due to the way the two packages interact with respect to the debugging strategies.

In this case one could adopt the [solution found by Mike Ivanov](https://gist.github.com/mikeivanov/25dc4d4c2cbfc6cfb5d4), that redefines the `swank-debugger-hook` function before starting Swank:

```
(in-package swank)

(setq swank-debugger-hook-orig #'swank-debugger-hook)

(defun swank-debugger-hook (condition hook)
  (etypecase condition
    (sb-int:simple-stream-error
      (progn
        (princ "*** Stream error" *error-output*)
        (abort)))
    (t (funcall swank-debugger-hook-orig condition hook))))

(in-package cl-user)

(swank:create-server :port 4008 :dont-close t)
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't really work with threads:

      CL-USER> *debugger-hook* => #<FUNCTION MY-DEBUG> 

And then:

      CL-USER> (bordeaux-threads:make-thread (lambda () (princ *debugger-hook*))) => #<FUNCTION SWANK:SWANK-DEBUGGER-HOOK>

Comment: It could be that, by using slime, swank overrides the definition of \*debugger-hook\*. I will look at the documentation of slime.

Comment: I think there might some kind of a thread startup hook that slime uses for setting up the debugger hook in new threads...

Comment: In slime there is sldb-hook "This hook is run after SLDB is invoked. The hook functions are called from the SLDB buffer after it is initialized. An example use is to add sldb-print-condition to this hook, which makes all conditions debugged with SLDB be recorded in the REPL buffer.". Try to change this.

Comment: The documentation is [here](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Hooks.html#Hooks).

Comment: Here is the description of SWANK:\*GLOBAL-DEBUGGER\*: "When true (the default) this causes \*DEBUGGER-HOOK\* to be globally set to SWANK:SWANK-DEBUGGER-HOOK and thus for SLIME to handle all debugging in the Lisp image. This is for debugging multithreaded and callback-driven applications." So, you could try to set it to NIL.

Comment: I've changed the answer.

Comment: I think I found a solution that works with sbcl - https://gist.github.com/mikeivanov/25dc4d4c2cbfc6cfb5d4. The only caveat is that the hook function has to be patched before starting Swank. @Renzo - would you update your answer so that I could accept it?

Comment: Updated. It works for CCL too. Clever solution, indeed! :)

Answer (score 5):

You can subclass `PROCESS-CONNECTION` for your acceptor and do your own error handling for this error.

Let's start by defining a custom acceptor:

```
(defclass no-error-acceptor (hunchentoot:acceptor)
  ())
```

Then we can create a wrapper around `PROCESS-CONNECTION` that inhibits printing of a message for this specific error:

```
(defmethod hunchentoot:process-connection ((acceptor no-error-acceptor) (socket t))
  (handler-case
      (call-next-method)
    (sb-impl::simple-stream-perror (condition)
      ;; Perhaps log the error here?
      nil)))
```

Make sure you actually start the server using this acceptor in order for it to be used.

Comment: Thank you. That's definitely a good approach, but still: is there a way to prevent SLDB from starting without actually fixing the problem? Say, if there is no source available, no way to subclass/override or some other constraints. Just curious.

Comment: You call the function to start hunchentoot from somewhere, if you install a handler around that call, it should (I believe) handle the error signalled and only unhandled errors should trigger the debugger.

Comment: @Vatine - nope, that happens in another thread => outside of the handler around the startup call.